# linq to sql-how to deleted a record from datacontext

Tags: linq-to-sql

I use a static datacontext for CRUD operation.

When I create some records in the gridview, then delete some of them, and then update the database, the deleted records are also inserted.

I guess maybe the deleted records are deleted from the gridview1.datasource, but they are not deleted from the datacontext.

But how can I deal with it?

Thanks very much.

code:

```
public class PurchaseOrderService{
private static readonly BaseEntityDao<PurchaseOrder> ObjDataAccess = new BaseEntityDao<PurchaseOrder>();
    public static void InsertRecord(PurchaseOrder localTable)
        {
            ObjDataAccess.Add(localTable);
        }
}


public class BaseEntityDao<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            NBDataLinqDataContext.Instance().GetTable<TEntity>().InsertOnSubmit(entity);
            SubmitChanges(NBDataLinqDataContext.Instance());
        }
    }

partial class NBDataLinqDataContext
    {
private static NBDataLinqDataContext instance;
public static NBDataLinqDataContext Instance()
        {
            // Uses "Lazy initialization"
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new NBDataLinqDataContext();
            instance.Log = Console.Out;
            return instance;
        }
}
```

winform code:

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
var po = new PurchaseOrder();
foreach (PurchaseOrderDetail pd in _list)
                        {
                            po.PurchaseOrderDetail.Add(pd);
                        }
PurchaseOrderService.InsertRecord(po);
}
```

Comment: You need to post the relevant code.

Comment: OK,code has been posted.

Comment: I'll need to look at this in-depth later, but your "lazy init" is not thread-safe. Further, there's no reason to write code like this anymore - just use a `Lazy<T>` or `Lazy<NBDataLinqDataContext>` in this case.

Comment: I write a var test=NBDataLinqDataContext.Instance().GetChangeSet(); to test, and I find that the objects deleted in the gridview still there.